# script to check if the URL are up and running

Tags: monitoring, curl, nginx

I have written a script to check if our three URLs are up.And if they are down I will need to send a message stating the url's are  down and not active.

The problem is, I did something wrong and now in any scenarios my output always shows the  "URLs are up"

FYi.. we use nginx and and hence why i has grep the output for  "http 302 found"

```
if curl -k --head $URL1 | grep "302 Found" && curl  -k --head $URL1 | grep "302 Found" && curl  -k --head $URL1 | grep "302 Found"
then
  echo "All The URLs are up!"
else
  echo " all url is down "
fi
```

Comment: What does "else intimate but her even" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
#!/bin/bash              

for URL in <url1> <url2> <url3>
    do                     
    STATUS=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" $URL)
      if [ $STATUS == 302 ] ; then
          echo "$URL is up, returned $STATUS"
      else                     
          echo "$URL is not up, returned $STATUS"
      fi
    done
```